# Supervisord loading old config

Tags: linux, laravel, ssh, supervisord

I'm using Supervisord to queue my Laravel jobs. Today I updated the config files and did the usual `supervisorctl reread` and `supervisorctl update`. Nevertheless, i didn't get any updated config files.

`whereis supervisord` results in `supervisord: /usr/bin/supervisord /etc/supervisord.conf`

`whereis supervisor` results in `` (empty response)

The `/etc/supervisord.conf` has the following

```
[include]
files=/var/www/vhosts/myfirstdomain/myfolder/ms_super.conf
files=/var/www/vhosts/myseconddomain/myfolder/th_super.conf
```

The path is correct and the files are setup exactly the same. I changed my PHP code for the worker and had to restart the service.

My struggle is that it's not updating, and I tried `reload` and `restart all`, it keeps running the old config file. I believe it's stored somewhere as cache or something.

My package manager is `yum`. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Reloading the master supervisor process may work, but it will have unintended side effects if you have more than one process being monitored by supervisor.

The correct way to do it is to issue supervisorctl reread which causes it to scan configuration files for any changes:

root@debian:~# supervisorctl reread
gunicorn: changed
Then, simply reload that app:

root@debian:~# supervisorctl restart gunicorn
gunicorn: stopped
gunicorn: started

Comment: The issue can be explained in a different way. It says "new process added" and everything when I type `supervisorctl reread update`, but the moment I do a `start all`, somehow, it's loading the content of the old config and saving it in the new one. I honestly dont know how

Comment: I figured it out. I had two files in the `include` instead of one,  so there was an issue with that for no reason. The weird thing was that the `supervisor` was calling the old config which doesn't even exist. I deleted the whole package and installed. So basically I just combined my two `workers` into one file and put that under `[include]`.